# return multiple values index and transpose google sheet

Tags: indexing, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I'd like to return all matching values of column A sheet1 from sheet2. So that for each hashtag (sheet1) all the titles that contain this hashtag are returned and transposed. I tried to apply the index function with if contains, but wasn't able to manage getting the data. Thanks.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XYNh8PPBaeZZXFyqBrwx3IFIi4xOBp0jfPygKXtuI5U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,sheet2!$A$2:$A)), sheet2!$A$2:$A, ""),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,sheet2!$A$2:$A)), sheet2!$A$2:$A, "")<>"")))
```

Paste this in B2 of sheet1 and copy it down, should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

in B2 sheet1

```
=iferror(transpose(query(ARRAYFORMULA(split(flatten(({split(sheet2!$A$2:$A," ")&"|"&sheet2!$B$2:$B})),"|")),"select Col2 where Col1 = '"&A2&"' ",0)))
```